# parse an XML file into a dictionary with xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

Provided I have a XML response as:

```
from lxml import etree
XML_string= '''<div type="description" xml:base="elpais.es" xml:lang="es" xml:id="f0910b98">
<p xml:id="_657a490035" n="0001">blabla1</p>
<p xml:id="_657a490036" n="0002">blabla2. bla bla 2.</p>
<p xml:id="_657a490037" n="0003">blabla3.blabla3</p>
<p xml:id="_657a490038" n="0004">bla4</p></div>'''
```

I parse it as follows:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False, strip_cdata=False, recover=True, ns_clean=True)
XML_tree = etree.fromstring(XML_string.encode() , parser=parser)
```

I am after transforming the XML into a dict as follows:

```
result_list = [{'id':"_657a490035", 'n':'001', 'text':'blabla1'},
{'id':"_657a490036", 'n':'002', 'text':'blabla2'}
etc
```

I am very close seeing this:

```
all_paras = XML_tree.xpath('.//p[@xml:id]')
result_list = []
for para in all_paras:
    result_list.append({'text':para.text,'id':'id?','n':'n??'})
```

I dont know how to access the content of the attributes in the node para.

Some help?

EDIT:
Be aware taht if you do:

```
for para in all_paras:
     print(para.attrib)
```

I get the strange dict:

```
 '{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id': '_657a490035', 'n': '0001'}
```

For some reason xml:id gets into this: {http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id'

Comment: I don't have an answer for your exact question; but faced with a similar task my approach was to use LMXL and XSLT to turn the XML into a CSV of key-value pairs; then just iterate through the CSV to create the dictionary.

I had reasons to do it this way; my target implementation was a C# .net library, and the Python was intended only as a prototype (though it's since taken on a life of its own), and the XSLT approach let me separate the XML parsing from the language-specific stuff. You can see it at https://github.com/codingatty/Plumage-py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting entangled with namespaces, unfortunately. One way to handle the problem is to use `local-name()`:

```
for para in all_paras:   
    #I simplified the id attribute value a bit, for simplicity 
    result_list.append({'id':para.xpath('./@*[local-name()="id"]')[0],'n':para.xpath('./@*[local-name()="n"]')[0],'text':para.text})
result_list
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '1', 'n': '0001', 'text': 'blabla1'},
 {'id': '2', 'n': '0002', 'text': 'blabla2. bla bla 2.'},
 {'id': '3', 'n': '0003', 'text': 'blabla3.blabla3'},
 {'id': '4', 'n': '0004', 'text': 'bla4'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

`xml:` in `xml:lang`, `xml:id` and `xml:base` is [a special namespace prefix](https://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace), bound to the `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace` namespace URI. Unlike any other prefix, it does not need to be declared in the XML document.

You can get the values of the `xml:id` attributes via `xpath()`, like this:

```
for para in all_paras:
    result_list.append({'text': para.text, 'id': para.xpath('@xml:id')[0]})
```

You could also use the `get()` method, but then you would have to provide the full namespace URI enclosed in braces:

```
for para in all_paras:
    result_list.append({'text': para.text, 'id': para.get("{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id")})
```